# Find phrase with prefix with AWS SDK for PHP on CloudSearch

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

In our backoffice we will use Cloudsearch for the search part instead of some Mysql request.

The problem is that I have some trouble to obtain the same result with Cloudsearch and I'd like some help if possible...

For example, if user search "**Alexandre Call**" :

**With Mysql** : one result for an event named "**Alexandre** & blablabla **Call**XXX"

For more information, the Mysql request use some `... WHERE CONCAT(FIELD1, " ", FIELD2, " ", FIELD 3) LIKE '%alexandre%' AND CONCAT(FIELD1, " ", FIELD2, " ", FIELD 3) LIKE '%call%'` for my example.

**With Cloudsearch** : 280 results, with event that contain "**Alexandre**" OR event that contain "**call**" or word with suffixe "**call** + something"

This is how I use Cloudsearch with `AWS SDK for PHP` :

**1/ I connect to my search domain :**

```
$client = CloudSearchDomainClient::factory(array(
    'endpoint' => 'https://XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com',
    'validation' => false,
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => _S3_API_KEY_,
        'secret' => _S3_API_SECRET_,
    ],
    'region' =>  'eu-west-1',
));
```

**2/ My research :**

```
$search_result['event'] = $client->search(
    array(
        // This is what user search, in my example $query = "Alexandre Call"
        'query'        => $query, 
        'queryOptions' => '{
                             "defaultOperator" : "or",
                             "fields":["description","nomevent^3", "idftpevent^2"]
                           }',
        'queryParser'  => 'simple',
        'size'         => 500,
        'start'        => 0
    )
);
```

With this I get 280 results as I said...**any idea how I can obtains similar result that I have with mysql?**

**Edit :**

I think I'd like to search something like this but I don't know how :

```
(and 
  (or description='alexandre' nomevent='alexandre' idftpevent='alexandre') 
  (or description='call' nomevent='call' idftpevent='call')
)
```

But impossible to make it works...the idea should be to have `alexandre` at least once in the 3 fields I search and same for `call` (for term like call, calling, callXXX...), any idea?

**Edit 2** :

I tried the solution for my example:

```
$event_query = 'alexander* call*';

$search_result['event'] = $client->search(
    array(
        'query'        => $event_query,
        'queryOptions' => '{
                               "defaultOperator": "and",
                               "fields":["nomevent^3","idftpevent^2", "description"]
                           }',
        'queryParser'  => 'simple',
        'size'         => 500,
        'start'        => 0
    )
);
```

But I got no result...I did somehting wrong?

I have trouble to understand what `"defaultOperator": "and",` is used for? It means I search for `alexandre*` AND `call*` or it means I search for `alexandre*` and `call*` in the 3 fields I mention?

As I showed before, I'd like to search for `alexandre*` in one of the 3 fields I mention AND `call*` in at least one of the 3 fields I mention

Comment: where is your PHP code for the mysql call?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I thought it wasn't pertinent here, I don't want to do the same so...the request is kinda complex will lot of think outof topic here.

Comment: essentially it'll be a like query. you may want to explode the string on spaces, and then it would be `LIKE '%wordone%wordtwo%etc%`

Comment: I added the mysql information as you asked but I want to achieve it with Cloudsearch using AWS SDK for PHP

Comment: oh, I got your question the wrong way around, i thought aws returned the correct stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I'd like to search something like this but I don't know how :
>
> ```
> (and 
>   (or description='alexandre' nomevent='alexandre' idftpevent='alexandre') 
>   (or description='call' nomevent='call' idftpevent='call')
> )
> ```

This is pretty close, but I think you can simplify this *a lot* by leveraging the built-in operators from the `simple` query parser.  With that parser, prefix queries use `*` at the end of a word or phrase to indicate that you're searching for matches that begin with the preceding characters. So your query should look like one of the following:

```
/* Only treat the last word as a prefix */

alexandre call*

/* Treat each word as a prefix */

alexandre* call*
```

Now, to match the `and` logic of the compound query that you tried, you just need to change your `defaultOperator` to `and` (or remove that option, because `and` is the default).

Hope that helps!

Reference: [AWS CloudSearch Documentation - Searching for Prefixes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html#searching-text-prefixes)

Comment: I will try you solution, I finally manage to make my query works with AWS SDK for php as I wanted BUT I got my result if I have `callXX` and not just `call`. I will try your solution, it's closer of what I want :)

Comment: I tried it but I have no result, I should have one...did I made something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I accept the other solution but I will still add what I really did if people want to see how it looks with `AWS SDK for PHP` :

**1/ I get what user search and "clean" the search :**

```
$_REQUEST['search'] = preg_replace(
    array('/\+/', '/-/', '/~/', '/>/', '/</', '/"/', '/\'/', '/\)/', '/\(/'), 
    "", 
    $_REQUEST['search']
);
```

**2/ Then I explode the search to get each word one by one :**

```
$word_list = explode(" ", trim($_REQUEST['search']));
```

**3/ Now I can build my request :**

```
// I start my query     
$event_query = "(and ";

// Now for each word, I add my condition :
// - I want each searched word in at least one of my 3 fields (nomevent, idftpevent and description)
// - I want the exact word or just a prefix
foreach ($word_list as $word) {
    $event_query .= "(or 
                       (prefix field=description '".$word."')
                       (prefix field=nomevent '".$word."')
                       (prefix field=idftpevent '".$word."')
                       (term field=description '".$word."')
                       (term field=nomevent '".$word."')
                       (term field=idftpevent '".$word."')
                     )";
}

// I close my query
$event_query .= ")";
```

**4/ Now I just have to use `AWS SDK for PHP` to get my result :**

```
$search_result['event'] = $client->search(
    array(
        'query'        => $event_query,
        'queryParser'  => 'structured',
        'size'         => 500,
        'start'        => 0
    )
);

$search_result['event'] = $search_result['event']->toArray();
```

And the result are in `$search_result['event']['hits']['hit']`, there is maybe a better way to get those `hit` but this way I achieve what I wanted !